# Styling in angular.js app

Tags: css, angularjs

There are two buttons on same page buy and sell. It seems, there's only one html instance for both of them. So when I try to style them with class, or id, or other html-targeted selector, I style both of them at the same time with same rules.

While I need different styles for each of them. How can I target each of them separately?
I tried something like

```
ng-style="{'background-color': order.orderType == 1 ?  '  #f6698b' : '#f6698b', 'border-color': order.orderType == 1 ?  '#73a839' : '#c71c22' }"
```

But it doesn't affect them separately, so how could I target them?

The html instance I'm talking about:

```
<button  class="button_buy btn btn-primary pull-right" style="width: 72px;    height:35px; text-align: center;" ng-style="{'background-color': order.orderType     == 1 ?  '  #f6698b' : '#f6698b', 'border-color': order.orderType == 1 ?      '#73a839' : '#c71c22' }">
                    {{ label[order.orderType == 1 && 'buy' || 'sell'] }}
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline styling isn't the proper way of styling. You should use `css`. Also you can easyly distinguish between different stylings for each `css class`. Take a look into [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp), if you don't know how `css` works.

Also, as I can see, you are using some Angular to distinguish which css property to use. This could be solved by using Angulars [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button_buy {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-image:none;
}

.button_buy[label="buy"] {
    background-color:Red;
    border-color:Purple;
}

.button_buy[label="sell"] {
    background-color:Yellow;
    border-color:Orange;
}
```

Comment: it didnt work, probaply because label donest exist as html instance here

Answer (score 0):

ng-style attribute should return an object. you could define the logic in the controller and put the function in the attribute that returns the style object.

```
//in the controller
$scope.getStyleForFirstButton = ->
  "color":"red"

$scope.getStyleForSecondButton = ->
  "color":"blue"

//in your template
button(ng-style="getStyleForFirstButton()")
button(ng-style="getStyleForSecondButton()")
```

the CSS only solution should do this better and faster so no extra watchers will be involved.

```
button:nth-child(1){
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Tried the nths child - didnt work, when I look at the html in chrome inspector, there's always one button, the parent element has, but in fact, You can see two of them. I think angular somehow generates them using one html instance

Comment: It is not possible. even generated, it should be in HTML and style applies immediately.

Comment: I wish so, but in fact it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

The way I did was fine, just probably the button has some styles from bootstrap and it replaced mine, once I removed all the bootstrap classes, the order.orderType distinct worked out